# iOS 10 bug? NSDate hour description with Japan region and 24-Hour Time off

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, ios10

This seems like an iOS 10 bug.  It is OK in iOS 8 and 9.

The hour description is wrong for [NSDate date].description.  It is appending the 24 hour description and 12 hour description.  I am not using NSDateFormatter.  Just the default settings.

On a real iOS 10 device, in Settings:

- Set Region to Japan in Settings > General > Language & Region > Region Formats > Region
- Set 24-Hour Time Off in Settings > General > Date & Time > 24-Hour Time

Then with:

```
NSLog(@"Date is %@", [NSDate date].description);
```

Actual log output:

```
Date is 2016-11-14 44:14:57 AM +0000
```

Expected output:

```
Date is 2016-11-14 4:14:57 AM +0000
```

Edit (Adding another example):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a";
NSString *dateString = @"1985-04-12 7:20:50 PM";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"Date is %@", date.description);
```

Actual output:

```
Date is 1985-04-12 1010:20:50 AM +0000
```

Expected output

```
Date is 1985-04-12 10:20:50 AM +0000
```

If I change the hour to 24 hour format (HH):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a";
NSString *dateString = @"1985-04-12 7:20:50 PM";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"Date is %@", date.description);
```

Actual output:

```
Date is (null)
```

Expected output:

```
Date is 1985-04-12 10:20:50 AM +0000
```

Comment: 24-hour time is not enabled, it is off

Comment: Submit a bug report to Apple. Be sure to include a trivial sample app that replicates the problem so they can fix it.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Apple.  Thanks for the advice

Comment: @unitwhy Any explanations on the anomaly?

Comment: @Sulabh I contacted Apple Developer Technical Support about it and they said to “Use Formatter Styles to Present Dates and Times With the User’s Preferences” section of the Data Formatting Guide  linked here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW3

Comment: @unitwhy Thank you

Answer (score 2):

We were also facing similar issue for iOS 10.x and fixed it using

NSLocale *POSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
            dateFormatter.locale should equal(POSIXLocale);