# Getting date from string with HH:mm time format is not working for Japanese language and region in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get date from string using DateFormatter(). My phone is set to Japan region, Language to Japanese and time to 12 hour format. My app is set to 24 hour format so that user can select time from custom picker in 24 hour format. The Date string is "11 3月, 2019 15:35". The date formatter is "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm". But it is not working and returns nil always.

According to [iOS 10 bug? NSDate hour description with Japan region and 24-Hour Time off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40581850/ios-10-bug-nsdate-hour-description-with-japan-region-and-24-hour-time-off)
If i use "MMM dd, yyyy KK:mm" as date format then it works only if the time in string is bellow 12:00. Here is my code below.

```
static func dateFrom(string: String, timeString: String) -> Date? {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current

    /// Check time format
    var timeFormat = "KK:mm"
    if timeString.containsIgnoringCase(find: AppConstants.am.localizedStringWith()) || timeString.containsIgnoringCase(find: AppConstants.pm.localizedStringWith()) {
        timeFormat =  "h:mm a"
    }
    /// Check date for MMDD format
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy \(timeFormat)"
    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string) {
        return date
    }
    /// Check date for DDMM format
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM, yyyy \(timeFormat)"
    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string) {
        return date
    }

    return dateFormatter.date(from: string)
}
```

Please let me know if you found solution for it.

Comment: The date formatter is "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm" => It does not make sense.

Comment: It is working fine with English language. @ElTomato

Comment: Try removing the timeStyle, it might be clashing with your dateFormat.

Comment: @Adis I tried but it do not work. This is working fine when region is other than Japan. I think there might be some time format variation for Japanese region. That is why I put this question here.

Comment: Did you try setting the calendar on the dateFormatter as well? I'm a bit lazy to setup everything to test Jp on my own.

Comment: @Adis Which calendar I should select for it?.

Comment: Try the gregorian for starters, and see where that takes you.

Comment: Thanks @Adis. It worked. I am testing it for other languages as well. Though much appreciate your help.

Comment: I'll put this into an answer so someone looking at this later might find it easily.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with dates in Japanese locales usually occur when the calendar is set to Japanese in device settings. Here's how I solved this problem:

```
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
```

and using `Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)` instead of `Calendar.current`.

Comment: It doesn't because dateFormatter.calendar = .gregorian results in error in Swift. Please try the solutions before rushing to give an opinion. I just had this issue and shared the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the calendar on your date formatter:

```
dateFormatter.calendar = .gregorian
```